# When is ExecutionContext#reportFailure(Throwable) called?

Tags: scala

This is a rather general question, but hopefully a reasonable one. When is `ExecutionContext#reportFailure(Throwable)` called?

It doesn't seem to be called in the Scala standard library. I suppose I perhaps should call it in some circumstances? What are these?

Answer (score 5):

This method reports exceptions that cannot be reported otherwise.

It is called when an exception happens during the execution of a callback that has no other way of reporting failure. In particular, calls to `Future.onComplete` (e.g. via `Future.foreach`) return `Unit` and may be executed on any thread, so they have no way of reporting failure back to their callers. When an exception is thrown within `onComplete`, it is sent to this method.

Answer (score 2):

It is called a couple of times deep within the implementation for `Promise` in the standard library. See the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/96f230a0e9c254c45dc91c71b5929639e6add1f0/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala#L60).

```
try onComplete(value) catch { case NonFatal(e) => executor reportFailure e }
```

An `ExecutionContext` can implement `reportFailure` to execute arbitrary code when a future/promise fails. The only thing in the standard library that implements this method is `ExecutionContextImpl`, which is not in the public API, but found [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/99a82be91cbb85239f70508f6695c6b21fd3558c/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/ExecutionContextImpl.scala#L18-L22). This class accepts a `reporter: Throwable => Unit` function. The default `ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` uses [`ExecutionContext.defaultReporter`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext$@defaultReporter:Throwable=%3EUnit), which simply prints the stack trace to `System.err`.

If you wanted to customize the behavior, you could need to define your own `ExecutionContext`. It's difficult to imagine a scenario where you'd want to produce some other side-effect other than logging the stack trace, or some other kind of logging.